# Fusion Tables v1 new JSON returned isn't working with jqGrid & jsonReader

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, google-fusion-tables

This is my code that worked with the beta of Fusion Tables (below is part of the jqGrid code that Oleg helped me with the other year):

```
jsonReader: {
repeatitems: false,
cell: "", // the same as cell: function (obj) { return obj; }
root: "table.rows",
page: function (obj) { return 1; },
total: function (obj) { return 1; },
records: function (obj) { return obj.table.rows.length; }
},
```

and here is the OLD JSON data returned from Google:

```
jQuery16406014587786572121_1350317794100(
{"table":
    {
    "cols":
        ["id","latitude","longitude","name","address_line_1","address_line_2","address_line_3","postcode"],
    "rows":
        [[1234,"55",-1.5, --etc
```

With the new API from Google, the JSON returned now looks like this:

```
{
"kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
"columns": [
    "id",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "name",
    "address_line_1",
    "address_line_2",
    "address_line_3",
    "postcode"
],
"rows": [
    [
        "1234",
        "55",
        -1.5,
        "Name One",
        "Road 1",
        "Road 2",
        "Sunderland",
        "SR1 1AA"
    ],
```

It doesn't seem to have a 'root', and I couldn't work out how to get the jsonReader to work with this new JSON. I have had a Google around to see if others have run into this, but only one or two unanswered hits re. java. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only that "table" part are removed from the JSON response. So I suppose you can try the following `jsonReader`:

```
jsonReader: {
    cell: "",
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.rows.length; }
}
```

Additionally you can include `id: 0` in `jsonReader` or use `key: true` for the `"id"` column definition (in `colModel`).

By the way I don't think that `repeatitems: false` is correct setting for the old format of data.

Comment: thanks Oleg - I'll check that out later/tomorrow - I had tried setting root: "", but I hadn't tried just leaving it out completely

Comment: @JPMox: Setting `root: ""` will be wrong for your data. I removed `root` because you need use `root: "rows"` which is *default* setting of jqGrid. I suppose that your main problem was the usage of `repeatitems: false` which is wrong for the data. Correct are *default* value `repeatitems: true`. One can omit default properties so there are no `repeatitems` in the `jsonReader` from my answer.